# Is there a "first_or_build" method on has_many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

In rails 3.2+, you can do this :

```
SomeModel.some_scope.first_or_initialize
```

Which means you can also do :

```
OtherModel.some_models.first_or_initialize
```

I find this pretty useful, but i'd like to have a `first_or_build` method on my `has_many` associations, which would act like `first_or_initialize` but *also add a new record to the association as `build` does when needed*.

**update for clarification** : yes, i know about `first_or_initialize`and `first_or_create`. Thing is, `first_or_initialize`does not add the initialized record to the association's target as `build` does, and `first_or_create`... well... *creates* a record, which is not the intent.

**I have a solution that works, using association extensions :**

```
class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :some_models do 
    def first_or_build( attributes = {}, options = {}, &block )
      object = first_or_initialize( attributes, options, &block )
      proxy_association.add_to_target( object ) if object.new_record?
      object
    end
  end

end
```

**I just wonder if :**

- built-in solutions to this problem already exist ?
- my implementation has flaws i do not see ?

Comment: What if you want perform eager loader on `OtherModel.some_models` at some point? I would rather perform such initialization in an `after_initialize` callback, its much cleaner approach IMO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is anything built into rails that will do exactly what you want, but you could mimic the first_or_initialize code with a more concise extension than you are currently using, which I believe does what you want, and wrap it into a reusable extension such as the following. This is written with the Rails 3.2 extend format.

```
module FirstOrBuild
  def first_or_build(attributes = nil, options = {}, &block)
    first || build(attributes, options, &block)
  end
end

class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :some_models, :extend => FirstOrBuild
end
```

Comment: Quite right. I don't know why I overingeneered this that way, this is obviously better.

Comment: In order to get this to work in Rails 4.1.0.beta, I had to specify the proxy association inside the scoping context; such that the extension reads `first || scoping{ proxy_association.build(attributes, &block) }` (without options anywhere) and the invocation looks like `Post.first.comments.where(foo: 'bar').first_or_build`. Also I used the new syntax has_many :posts, -> { extending FirstOrBuild } on Post.)

Comment: @ChrisKeele thanks for the update. Does this still work as intended when you do things like `foo.bars.where(title: 'buzz').first_or_build` ? (i.e. a new bar is added to foo.bars, and it has 'buzz' as title). As a side note, I just noticed that first_or_create does not add the record to the proxy_association's target, either. Maybe I should file a ticket to the rails team, the current state of the API does not follow the principle of least surprise IMHO

Comment: I also find it surprising, though there my be some reason why it's not default behaviour.

Comment: `foo.bars.where(title: 'buzz').first_or_build(desc: 'baz')` still finds by `title` if it exists, builds a record with the expected `title` and `desc` if not, and adds the `bar` to `foo`'s collection of them.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.17 and I had to use @ChrisKeele's code (which works like a charm). Just a head's up to other folks reading this--the accepted answer won't work for some versions of Rails 3.2.